# how to not expose server info when loading and connecting to socket

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I have drupal site that communicates with Node.js server via sockets, so i have the following to load and send connection request in the header:

```
 <script src="http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
... 
socket = io.connect('http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3000');
```

This works well, however. I prefer my server ip and the port number is not exposed to the rest of the world. What is the approach to do so? Thank You

Comment: Er... use your FQDN? If you don't have one, register one and DNS it to that IP address

Comment: Hiding your ip and port doesn't does anything for you. I would not worry about it.

Comment: If you don't give them your server ip and port, they won't be able to visit you. It's simple: Don't put a site on the web, and everything is fine.

Comment: Thank You Bojangles, Bart. Bergi, could there be a case your interface(say drupal site) is socketing with some other app(say Node.js) that you don't want it to be exposed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is :

**You can not do this.**

The longer explaination :

Your `socket.io` connection is like any other connection made to your server(s). It will be always visible in the developer tools of any other browser. You might want to use a proxy service for that, but in the end your `socket.io` server will always be exposed.

Nobody will ever read your JS code if he wants to get your `socket.io` IP-address, there are many other easier ways to do that.

Although you can always use the `autoconnect` feature of socket.io and just put

```
socket = io.connect();
```